# Sorting data and generating table outputs from CSV file in Python

Tags: python, csv

Let's say I've got the following CSV file (subjects.csv)

```
subjects,name1,name2,name3
Chemistry,Tom,Will,Rob
Biology,Megan,Sam,Tim
Physics,Tim,Will,Bob
Maths,Will,Tim,Joe
```

I want to find which pairs of students share the same class, focusing only on Tim, Tom and Will. How would I go about pairing these in Python?

i.e.

Tim and Will attend 2 classes together.

Tom and Will attend in 1 class together.

Furthermore, I want to plot this on a table like what I've written below, where it has names on both axis and the number of classes a pair of students both share (with names sorted in ascending or descending alphabetical order).. I've read about how to generate tables for entire CSV files, but I can't get my head around making tables from scratch whilst at the same time, stripping columns and rows from the CSV file..

```
             Tim        Tom     Will

    Tim   0           0       0

    Tom   0           0       1

    Will     2           0       0
```

This is way out of my personal skill level, but I'd still like to know how to do it and try to understand.

Comment: Throw your file away. It's just not realistic to have a fixed number of students per class. It's just not sensible to have a varying number of "name" columns in a file. You should have 2 columns, "Subject" and "Name". Also your output table is just not realistic. A realistic scenario would have hundreds or more of students ... 100 students means a table of 10000 elements which nobody is going to want to print or scroll through on the screen. Your previous question had columns name1, name2, name3. Are you making up these weird file designs, or is this a homework assignment?

Comment: I'm making up these files so that I can play around with them. What you said makes sense.. I should have used a better example, but I just wanted to understand sorting and generating tables using a CSV file.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a dictionary with what class each student is taking:

```
>>> import csv
>>> import collections
>>> D = collections.defaultdict(set)
>>> with open('subjects.csv','rb') as f:
...     subject_reader = csv.reader(f)
...     header = subject_reader.next()
...     for row in subject_reader:
...         for name in row[1:]:
...             D[name].add(row[0])
... 
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(dict(D))
{'Bob': set(['Physics']),
 'Joe': set(['Maths']),
 'Megan': set(['Biology']),
 'Rob': set(['Chemistry']),
 'Sam': set(['Biology']),
 'Tim': set(['Biology', 'Maths', 'Physics']),
 'Tom': set(['Chemistry']),
 'Will': set(['Chemistry', 'Maths', 'Physics'])}
>>>
```

To check how many classes people are taking together you can use set's intersection method:

```
>>> D['Tom'].intersection(D['Will'])
set(['Chemistry'])
>>> len(_)
1
>>> D['Tim'].intersection(D['Will'])
set(['Maths', 'Physics'])
>>> len(_)
2
>>>
```

To print out the table in your example you can do something like this:

```
>>> EXAMPLE_NAMES = ['Tom','Tim','Will']
>>> for y_name in EXAMPLE_NAMES:
...     print '{0:{width}}'.format(y_name,width=5),
...     for x_name in EXAMPLE_NAMES:
...         if y_name==x_name:
...             print '{0:{width}}'.format('-'*5, width=5),
...         else:
...             print '{0:{width}}'.format(len(D[y_name].intersection(D[x_name])), width=5),
...     print
... 
Tom   -----     0     1
Tim       0 -----     2
Will      1     2 -----
```

a header for the table might look like this:

```
    >>> for x_name in [' ']+EXAMPLE_NAMES:
    ...     print '{0:{width}}'.format(x_name, width=5),
    ... 
          Tom   Tim   Will
```

As John mentions in the comments, I am hard coding the names into a list, to mimic the example you gave above. To see an entire table you can get or iterate the keys from the dictionary you created using `.iterkeys()` or `.keys()`:

```
>>> import csv
>>> import collections
>>> 
>>> my_d = collections.defaultdict(set)
>>> with open('subjects.csv','rb') as f:
...     subject_reader = csv.reader(f)
...     header = subject_reader.next()
...     for row in subject_reader:
...         for name in row[1:]:
...             my_d[name].add(row[0])
... 
>>> def display_header(D):
...     for x_name in [' ']+D.keys():
...         print '{0:{width}}'.format(x_name, width=5),
...     print
... 
>>> def display_body(D):
...     for y_name in D.iterkeys():
...         print '{0:{width}}'.format(y_name,width=5),
...         for x_name in D.iterkeys():
...             if y_name==x_name:
...                 print '{0:{width}}'.format('-'*5, width=5),
...             else:
...                 print '{0:{width}}'.format(len(D[y_name].intersection(D[x_name])), width=5),
...         print
... 
>>> def display_table(D):
...     display_header(D)
...     display_body(D)
... 
>>> display_table(my_d)
      Sam   Rob   Megan Will  Tim   Joe   Tom   Bob  
Sam   -----     0     1     0     1     0     0     0
Rob       0 -----     0     1     0     0     1     0
Megan     1     0 -----     0     1     0     0     0
Will      0     1     0 -----     2     1     1     1
Tim       1     0     1     2 -----     1     0     1
Joe       0     0     0     1     1 -----     0     0
Tom       0     1     0     1     0     0 -----     0
Bob       0     0     0     1     1     0     0 -----
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for that.. I'll look into the intersection method, but is there a way to formulate a script that allows Python to pair names up automatically? Because if I add more names to the CSV, I'm guessing I'll have to add every name again to the existing code.. With that said, I would ignore the subject column altogether, cause it won't be part of the table?

Comment: You are creating a product of a list to itself using a nested for loop. To just get pairs you can look into itertools.product. to get the list of students after parsing the csv. You can use my_dict.keys()

Comment: -1 [rubber stamp comment] open csv files in binary mode if Python2.x else with `newline=''`

Comment: @NewPython: (1) You should NOT have any names in your code. All names should be in a (well-designed) file. (2) You can't ignore the subject column; it's essential when building the output table; you can't answer a question like "How many subjects do A and B have in common?" if you don't know what subjects A and B are taking!

Comment: @DTing: You need to insert a line like `TABLE_NAMES = sorted(D.iterkeys()` ... its absence may be the cause of the OP thinking that he needs to include all the names in his code.

Comment: Thanks, made some edits. Hope that's better. Was in a rush the first time around.

Comment: @DTing: I was confused, some small part of which was caused by your calling it "TABLE_NAMES" which is suggestive of all the possible names. I'd suggest `QUERY_NAMES` and also that it NOT be set to a list of hard-coded names but should be e.g. `QUERY_NAMES = sys.argv[1:]`